# How to draw a graph for comparing data from two different datasets in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

There are 2 dataset

```
Forecast=structure(list(sub = c("01.01.01 Automatic switches ARMAT", "01.01.01 Automatic switches ARMAT", 
"01.01.01 Automatic switches ARMAT", "01.01.02 Automatic switches KARAT", 
"01.01.02 Automatic switches KARAT", "01.01.02 Automatic switches KARAT"
), ds = c("01.05.2022", "01.06.2022", "01.07.2022", "01.05.2022", 
"01.06.2022", "01.07.2022"), forecast = c(30696L, 30696L, 30696L, 
1089910L, 1089910L, 1089910L), fct = c(22590L, 29243L, 30521L, 
803535L, 1430316L, 1312260L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

`sub` is grouping variable. `forecast` column is forecast on month(`ds` column).`Fact`  is real data.
Each forecast performed by group separately(sub column)

Also second dataset

```
manager_forecast=structure(list(sud = c("01.01.01 Automatic switches ARMAT", "01.01.01 Automatic switches ARMAT", 
"01.01.02 Automatic switches KARAT", "01.01.02 Automatic switches KARAT", 
"", ""), ds = c("01.06.2022", "01.07.2022", "01.06.2022", "01.07.2022", 
"", ""), manager_forecast = c(76011.04671, 113534.0746, 1802431.458, 
1399089.059, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

In this dataset same structure ,but here there is column `manager_forecast`  this is how much pieces the manager thought  would be sold.

Thus, for each group (sub) I need to draw a graph of correlations between how many pieces I predicted will be sold and how many were in fact (dataset forecast) and how much the manager assumed (manager_forecast)

I would like to get something like this graph for each sub (I did this in excel)
[image]

What is the easiest way for each sub to get such graphics and save them to the `C: / 1 / plots` folder.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to merge your two data frames according to sub and date, then pivot into long format. Plotting is then fairly straightforward, faceting by sub, and some theme tweaks to get a similar look to the Excel plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Forecast %>% 
  left_join(manager_forecast, by = c(sub = 'sud', ds = 'ds')) %>%
  pivot_longer(forecast:manager_forecast) %>%
  mutate(ds = lubridate::mdy(ds)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(ds, value, color = name)) +
  geom_line(size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar, name = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('dodgerblue', '#FF7820', 'gray95'), name = NULL) +
  facet_wrap(sub~., nrow = 2) +
  labs(x = 'Date') +
  theme_dark(base_size = 16) +
  theme(text = element_text(color = 'gray85'),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = '#303030'),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = '#303030'),
        legend.position = 'top',
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_text(color = 'gray85'),
        legend.key = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())

ggsave('path/to/my/plot.png')
```

**path/to/my/plot.png**

[image]